# How to use Google Bigquery's functions like FLATTEN or WITHIN in Tableau?

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api, flatten

I'm new to Tableau, but wondering how you could use some of Bigquery's functions that deals with nested data in Tableau? Is it only through writing Custom SQL?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tableau's custom SQL options, you could also consider adding a [BigQuery view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views) which can expose the flattened representation to Tableau.

Comment: True - just so I understand, when you have 2 nested structures in your table, will you flatten on one side and expose it as a view and use another view to expose the other side and then you'd end up joining it later in Tableau?

Comment: Its entirely dependent on your needs.  You could expose the joined data as a view if it makes sense.